# How can I display image on fullscreen when user taps on my UIImage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm displaying a photo in my app and I'm using `UIImage` for that. So far this is how I'm doing that:

```
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        }.resume()
}

func downloadImage(url: NSURL){
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            print("Download Finished")
            self.requestPhoto.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

and then in `viewDidLoad()` I'm doing:

```
if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: photo) {
        requestPhoto.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        downloadImage(checkedUrl)
    }
```

That leaves the UIImage filled with my photo, but it's not clickable and it's the size of the original component. Is there a way of adding some kind of listener or something that will display the photo on fullscreen when user taps the UIImage component?

Comment: Image will stretch if the size is less than the view size.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, I want to display the image as I'm displaying it now. But additionaly I want to give the user the possibility of displaying the image full screen (previewing it) when he taps it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `requestPhoto` image view. Something like this :

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapHandler"))

self.requestPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
self.requestPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

The last line is needed as `UIImageView` has it turned of by default, so the touches get canceled.

And then in the same class :

```
func tapHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
         // change the size of the image view so that it fills the whole screen
    }
}
```

The whole thing could also benefit from a flag saying if the view is fullscreen or not, so that when the user taps the fullscreen image you can reverse the process.

As always, you can read more in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UITapGestureRecognizer).

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, however I tried it and it does not work... I added the first two lines to `viewDidLoad` and the rest somewhere else in my class, but still no effect when I tap it. Is there possibly anything else left?

Comment: Yes, I actually forgot about one thing - image views have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `false` and this prevents the touch to be forwarded to the gesture recognizer. Just add `self.requestPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = true` in `viewDidLoad` and it should be fine. I also added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, in my case worked: `let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapHandler:")`, somehow when I used `action: Selector("tapHandler"))` it was throwing the `unrecognizable selector`... But now it works, thanks for your help!

Comment: One more thing @Losiowaty - I added a follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094792/how-can-i-set-programmatically-from-code-the-size-of-uiimageview-to-cover-full-s could you take a look at it? maybe you will be able to help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**How to enlarge thumbnail photo into fullscreen photo view on iOS?**

I resolved this problem by creating new UIImageView object with the same image in it and set the frame of it equal to thumbnail image:

```
let fullscreenPhoto = UIImageView(frame: thumbnailImage.frame)
```

Then add image as sublayer into main window:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first!.addSubview(fullscreenPhoto)
```

Resizing is made with animation using block:

```
let windowFrame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first!.frame
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

            fullscreenPhoto.frame = windowFrame
            fullscreenPhoto.alpha = 1
            fullscreenPhoto.layoutSubviews()

            }, completion: { _ in
        })
```

You can find ready solution here: https://github.com/lukszar/SLImageView

There is provided gesture recognizers for show and hide fullscreen.
You just need to set your UIImageView to SLImageView class in Storyboard and all magic is done.