# How can I set programmatically from code the size of uiimageview to cover full screen in my swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

This is actually a follow up to this question - [How can I display image on fullscreen when user taps on my UIImage in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031447/how-can-i-display-image-on-fullscreen-when-user-taps-on-my-uiimage-in-swift)

I managed to add a tap listener to my uiimageview, but now I would like to expand it when user clicks it. I have an iboutlet for that photo:

```
@IBOutlet weak var requestPhoto: UIImageView!
```

and then the listener so far prints this string:

```
func tapHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        print("photo tapped")
    }
}
```

Now instead of printing the string I want to show the photo on the full screen, but so that it could work on any size of the iphone screens - is there a way of doing that directly from the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easily :

```
self.requestPhoto.frame = self.view.frame
```

Bear in mind though, that this will not adjust after rotating the screen. If you support both portrait and landscape it would be best to get outlest for constraints and manipulate them.

Also this method will preserve navigation and tab bars (the photo won't cover them). If you want "full" fullscreen, you should take the frame of [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/)

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! And what about coming back to the small size? How can I bring it back to the original size since I set up the size in story board and not in the code?

Comment: Come on, that shouldn't be that hard to figure it out ;) Since you know which property of a view stores its size, just save it to a variable before enlarging it ;)

Comment: Thanks, with your clue it was easier than I thought! :) so one last question in this area - if the photo is on full screen, is there a way of making it "zoomable" to the user? I mean allowing user to zoom it for exsmple with moving with two fingers on it - as in standard ios way?

Comment: Ok, I just thought that with this approach there might be some quick fix for that... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set transparent UIButton and connect to another ViewController
2. Create new Viewcontroller and set new UIImageView
3. Go to Storyboard click segue symbol line and go to Right Panel Asisten Inspector
4. Set  Kind: Present Modally - Presentation: Current Context : Animates

[Storyboard Segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEcRl.png)